# V-if doesn't react to state change

Tags: vue.js

So I've got two columns, where first is inputs and second outputs the user input in a box. The functionality is that I can add with a click of a button, which works fine, but I also want to be able to delete selected boxes with an X icon as currently displayed. When I click the X icon to delete the box I expect the previous box's input form to appear but it won't until I click the box.

I originally had the delect function on a button outside of the for loop and it worked fine but need it to be with an X icon and I'm having these issues now. I've got a codepen set up with the code

```
  <div id="app">  
    <div class="columns is-v-centered">
    <div class="column is-5">
    <h2 class="help">Use <span class="tag">_keyword</span> tag to dynamically replace your keyword</h2>
    <div v-for="(ad, index) in ads" :key="index">
    <div v-if="ads[index]['boolean'] == true">
      <div class="form-inputs">
        <label class="label is-capitalized">Headline One</label>
        <div class="field">
          <div class="control is-expanded">
            <input type="text" class="input" v-model="ad.headline1" placeholder="Leave empty to skip this!">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-inputs">
        <label class="label is-capitalized">Headline Two </label>
        <div class="field">
          <div class="control is-expanded">
            <input type="text" class="input" v-model="ad.headline2" placeholder="headline 2">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-inputs">
        <label class="label is-capitalized">Headline Three </label>
        <div class="field">
          <div class="control is-expanded">
            <input type="text" class="input" v-model="ad.headline3" placeholder="healdine 3">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-inputs">
        <label class="label is-capitalized">Description One </label>
        <div class="field">
          <div class="control is-expanded">
            <input type="text" class="input" v-model="ad.desc1" placeholder="description one">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-inputs">
        <label class="label is-capitalized">Description Two </label>
        <div class="field">
          <div class="control is-expanded">
            <input type="text" class="input" v-model="ad.desc2" placeholder="description two">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-inputs">
        <label class="label is-capitalized">Final URL </label>
        <div class="field">
          <div class="control is-expanded">
            <input type="text" class="input" v-model="ad.finalurl" placeholder="www.books.com">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-inputs">
        <label class="label is-capitalized">Path One </label>
        <div class="field">
          <div class="control is-expanded">
            <input type="text" class="input" v-model="ad.path1" placeholder="path1">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-inputs">
        <label class="label is-capitalized">Path Two </label>
        <div class="field">
          <div class="control is-expanded">
            <input type="text" class="input" v-model="ad.path2" placeholder="path2">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="column is-2">

</div>
<div class="column is-5">
  <div class="field is-grouped is-grouped-right has-addons">
    <a id="blue-button-theme" class="button is-fullwidth" @click="newAd()">Create new ad</a>


  </div>
  <p class="help">Click on an ad and edit the values in the form. Your changes will be applied to all ad sets automatically.</p>
  <br>
  <div class="box ad-box" v-for="(ad, index) in ads" :key="index"@click="hideInput(index)">
    <div>
      <span> text| </span>
      <span class="icon is-pulled-right has-text-grey-light has-text-weight-light" @click="deleteAd()">
        <span v-if="ad.boolean">
          <p class="">X</p>
        </span>
      </span>
      <br>
      <span class="is-size-7 is-grey">{{ad.headline1}} </span>
    </div>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/luis4flames/pen/KJzrjb?editors=1010

Comment: Ha e u tried changing boolean key to some else e.g myboolean, maybe is a reserved word issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a version that seems to work. I've done two things:

- dumped the `for` - there's no need to go through all your ads. You're only interested in the one you're deleting
- and set `boolean` to true on [`$nextTick()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick).

```js
deleteAd(){
  let index = this.ads.findIndex(_a => _a.boolean);
  this.ads.splice(index, 1);
  this.$nextTick().then(() => {
    if (this.ads.length) {
      this.ads[Math.min(index, this.ads.length - 1)]["boolean"] = true;
    }
  });
},
```

[Updated pen](https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/WPxrMm?editors=1010).

By the way, another problem you have is your `newAd()` function currently requires your component to have at least 1 ad. I haven't fixed it. You probably want to implement an ad interface that can create new ads from scratch.

Comment: Great, thanks! It works but quick question, there seems to be a quick flutter when deleted the last ad. If i delete ad 1 or 2 out of 3 it's a seamless visual experience but when choosing the last one it's a bit weird. I can see the timeout function and notice there isn't a time set, I've tried to add 0 as time length but it breaks it, or I did it wrong. Do you have any idea of how to fix it?

Comment: The second param is `0` when not specified. it's done so it pushes code execution at the end of execution queue (when vue finishes what it's currently doing - kind of).

Comment: I'm working through other bugs that follow back to this specific function. Can you explain why you used setTimeout() to set the boolean value to true? What exactly does that do differently than just setting the value.

Comment: It is a default method to push code execution at the back of current execution queue. It is saying: *"when you get to this point, finish everything you're currently executing and **then** execute the code in this function."* Can you provide a [mcve] with the bugs you're experiencing?

Comment: A much better solution than `setTimeout()` is `$nextTick()` in Vue. I should have used it from the start. I've updated both answer and the pen. Let me know if it fixed your errors. If not, give me a chance to look at them.